# 1D Random-Walker Terminating Position Chance

Tags: python, math, random

I understand that the title is a bit unclear, but here is my problem.

'Bob, a Random-Walker, is standing at position X. When he reaches position 0, he would be so happy that he would live there forever. (i.e. stop walking).

But if he reaches position N, he would have a curse which makes him stay there forever.

Every second, Bob has a chance, T, to walk left one unit. He also has a chance (1 - T) to walk right one unit.

Determine the probability that he would find position 0 before he went into the curse (position N).'

Also, X, N are given as integers and T is given as p/q. I shall output the probability as a reduced fraction A/B with B>0.

Here is my question, but I have no clue how to tackle it. There are 3 subtasks:

1. N = 2
2. N <= 3
3. No additional constraints
   Default constraints: 0
   <
   X
   <
   N
   ≤
   10
   (so 
   N
   ≥
   2
   ), 
   0
   ≤
   p
   ≤
   q
   ≤
   50
   , 
   q
   >
   0
   .

N = 2 is pretty trivial, just output the given p/q.
~~~~~~
N = 3 is already hard for me to get the logic.
Test Case 1: X = 2, N = 3, p = 1, q = 2
The answer should be 1/3 .
~~~~~~ .
General case... No idea.
Any idea or help would be great!

Comment: This is really a mathematics question, not a coding question (although you can estimate the probability via simulation). So you may get more responses over on the Mathematics Stack Exchange. But do a search first to see if a similar question has already been asked there.

Comment: Okay. I asked it here because it was being asked in a coding contest. I guess it is a problem that require both math simplification and computer computation.

Comment: It would help if you know a little about [Markov chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain).

Comment: How @PM2Ring ? I have looked into Markov chains a bit but have no idea how it can help.

Comment: To make this a Markov chain, think of N+1 possible states--one state for each position 0 through N. States 0 and N are absorbing states. Now use the stated probabilities to set up your Markov chain matrix and analyze from there.

Answer (score 1):

I have got an answer from AoPS, and I would like to share it here.
Simply setup a system of equations:

Let P_X be the probability when starting at position X.
and T be the probability to hop left
and N be the cursed earth position.

`P_0 = 1`
`P_(n + 1) = T * P_n + (1 - T) * P_(n + 2)`
`P_N = 0`

From that, solve for P_X and that's your probability.

Elegant!